# Compiling a C file through Gedit external tools

Tags: compiling, gedit, c

Is there any way to compile and run .c files by using a shortcut key using gedit? I know its possible for java and C++, and I read somewhere that it is possible to do so using scripts in external tools. I'm currently compiling my files by gcc -Wall name name.c then ./name, but i would like to make this process faster

I already tried the below script for my shortcut but it generates an error saying

> fatal error: no input files

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME"
gcc  "$GEDIT_CURRENT_CODUMENT_NAME"
```

Comment: Your last line has a typo. Surely `"$GEDIT_CURRENT_CODUMENT_NAME"` should be `"$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME"`?

Comment: You might also want to look into learning about [makefiles](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/).

Answer (score 1):

The default build command of the gedit external tools works perfectly for me (run using Ctrl+F8):

[image]